# What features does "Link to Previous" preserve in Headers & Footers in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been trying to publish a large book with lots of sections, but when I tick off the boxes "Different First Page" or "Different Odd & Even Pages", there's ambiguous behavior depending on whether "Link to Previous" is checked. I've had to make many passes over my manuscript to make sure the headers and footers appeared exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment, and "Link to Previous" preserves the body of up to three pieces of formatted text: the first page, the odd page, and the even page.

When "Link to Previous" button is checked, then changes made to any of those three affect any linked section's three slots.

As for "Different First Page", the clicking action will set or unset the linked sections automatically, but each linked section can have its own setting.

As for "Different Odd & Even Pages", this is global to the document.